# Passing processed ... arguments to plot() via do.call()

Tags: r

I am trying to write a method that extends plot() for an S3 object that is essentially a list of `xy.coords()` lists.  I would like the flexibility to use `...` but I need to process the arguments therein for aesthetics (namely `xaxt` and `yaxt` arguments).  A test function I wrote is below:

```
#test of ... expansion and modification
test = function(x, ...) {
  # x is a list of xy.coords() lists
  
  vargs = list(...)
  str(vargs)
  #vargs = as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  # plotting defaults for aesthetics if they are not explicitly set
  if (!'xaxt' %in% names(vargs)) vargs[['xaxt']] = 'n'
  if (!'yaxt' %in% names(vargs)) vargs[['yaxt']] = 'n'
  if (!'pch' %in% names(vargs)) vargs[['pch']] = 16
  if (!'cex' %in% names(vargs)) vargs[['cex']] = 0.5
  print(vargs)
  
  pargs = c(list(x=x[[1]]$x, y=x[[1]]$y), vargs)
  str(pargs)
  
  do.call(plot, pargs) # this produces a crazy plot with a bunch of text
  
  plot(x=x[[1]], ...) # this produces the desired results
  
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

The call I issue is:

```
test(Y, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', pch=16, cex=0.5)
```

where (truncated for brevity):

```
> Y[[1]]
$x
  [1]  0.001111111  0.501388889  1.001388889  1.501388889  2.001388889  2.501388889  3.001388889  3.501388889  4.001388889

$y
  [1] 0.132 0.123 0.126 0.143 0.145 0.123 0.128 0.131 0.140
```

As I've indicated in the comments in `test()`, expanding `...` to a list of arguments and the passing that list to `plot` via `do.call` creates a plot with text scattered all over - like so:

[image: strange output from do.call(plot, pargs)]

Otherwise, passing `...` directly to `plot` does what I want:

[image: correct/expected plot output]

Is there something I'm doing wrong with,

- my processing of `...`?
- how I'm passing things to `do.call()`?

Am I missing a step/parameter entirely, or is this a bug in R?
Session info below and thanks in advance for your help.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] groan_1.0      roxygen2_2.2.2 digest_0.6.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] brew_1.0-6    stringr_0.6.2 tools_3.0.0
```

### EDIT

Here is a more copy+paste compatible version of my problem

```
#test of ... expansion and modification
test = function(x, method=c('do.call', 'dots'), ...) {
  # x is a list of xy.coords() lists
  
  vargs = list(...)
  str(vargs)
  #vargs = as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  # plotting defaults for aesthetics if they are not explicitly set
  if (!'xaxt' %in% names(vargs)) vargs[['xaxt']] = 'n'
  if (!'yaxt' %in% names(vargs)) vargs[['yaxt']] = 'n'
  if (!'pch' %in% names(vargs)) vargs[['pch']] = 16
  if (!'cex' %in% names(vargs)) vargs[['cex']] = 0.5
  print(vargs)
  
  pargs = c(list(x=x[[1]]), vargs)
  str(pargs)
  
  method = match.arg(method)
  switch(method, 
         do.call={
           do.call(plot, pargs) # this produces a crazy plot with a bunch of text
         }, dots={
           plot(x=x[[1]], ...) # this produces the desired results
         })
  
  invisible(NULL)
}

Y = list(xy.coords(runif(100), runif(100)))

# this produces a crazy plot with a bunch of text
test(Y, method='do.call', xaxt='n', yaxt='n', pch=16, cex=0.5)

# this produces the desired results
test(Y, method='dots', xaxt='n', yaxt='n', pch=16, cex=0.5)
```

### RESOLUTION

The solution by @shadow fixed my problem.  An alternative would also be to specify `ann=FALSE` as an argument in the list passed to `do.call()`.

Comment: Im not able to reproduce your graph.  Can you try creating a reproducible example (something that can be copy+pasted)  thanks

Comment: I would have imagined this would work: `pargs = list(x=x[[1]]$x, y=x[[1]]$y, vargs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the axis labels. You are essentially doing something similar to

plot(x=c(0.001111111,  0.501388889,  1.001388889,  1.501388889,  2.001388889,  2.501388889,  3.001388889,  3.501388889,  4.001388889,  0.501388889,  1.001388889,  1.501388889,  2.001388889,  2.501388889,  3.001388889,  3.501388889,  4.001388889,  0.501388889,  1.001388889,  1.501388889,  2.001388889,  2.501388889,  3.001388889,  3.501388889,  4.001388889,  0.501388889,  1.001388889,  1.501388889,  2.001388889,  2.501388889,  3.001388889,  3.501388889,  4.001388889,  0.501388889,  1.001388889,  1.501388889,  2.001388889,  2.501388889,  3.001388889,  3.501388889,  4.001388889,  0.501388889,  1.001388889,  1.501388889,  2.001388889,  2.501388889,  3.001388889,  3.501388889,  4.001388889,  0.501388889,  1.001388889,  1.501388889,  2.001388889,  2.501388889,  3.001388889,  3.501388889,  4.001388889))

To fix the problem just assign labels yourself:

```
if (!'xlab' %in% names(vargs)) vargs[['xlab']] = names(x[[1]][2])
if (!'ylab' %in% names(vargs)) vargs[['ylab']] = names(x[[1]][1])
```